# Does sshd sends data into stdin after SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exec

Tags: linux, ssh, stdin, sshd

I am writing part of the software that has to execute remote shell command. This command waits for some additional info from *stdin* in order to continue it's execution.

Here is the remote program *test_interactive.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Please, enter a string: "

read string         # <-- Wait here for the input to come...
if [ -z "$string" ] ; then
    echo "1. You entered empty string." 1>&2
else
    echo "1. Your string: $string"
fi
```

At this moment I am initiating the execution of my command with *SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST* exec message. Then after window adjustments and success message, I am sending *SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA* with the data that I'd like to be pushed into my program's *stdin* by *sshd* server. As it turned out, my program doesn't receive anything on *stdin*.

SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exec causes *sshd* process to spawn two additional processes *sshd*(63023) and ***test_interactive***(*63024*).
[image]

The process **test_interactive***(*63024*) has the following file descriptors:
[image]

And here is the sequence of messages that leads me to the state, where I'm sending messages and receiving back nothing from my program:

```
Send:    'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN session'
Receive: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION 0'
Send:    'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exec'
Receive: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST'
Receive: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS'
Receive: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA Please, enter a string:'
Send:    'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA hello'  <-- communication stops here
```

How should I instruct sshd to push data into stdin that it receives with *SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA*? I have tried to find it out by looking at the source code of sshd, but it's quite big and I think it will take weeks for me to figure this out :)

### Combination of requests that finally does it

The daemon *sshd* pushes data into *stdin* if you do the following:

1. Immediately after '*SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exec*' you send '*SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA Hello World*'
2. Immediately after '*SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA Hello World*' you send '*SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF*'

Or more illustratively:

```
Send:    'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exec'
Send:    'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA Hello World'
Send:    'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF'
Receive: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA Please, enter a string:'
Receive: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exit-status'
Receive: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA Please, enter a string: 1. Your string: Hello\n'
Receive: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF'
Receive: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE'
Send:    'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE'
Send:    'SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT'
```

This doesn't solve the problem, but gives a little bit more information on the *sshd*'s behaviour. I still need to be able to form my message for the program based on what has come to me, not just fire and forget.

By the way, it would be cool to add rfc4254 tag ;)
↓

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some of the actual code around the part that isn't working? Is this test_interactive program expecting its input to be terminated by a line terminator? Are you actually sending a line terminator as part of the data?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in the problem. I have updated my question.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the actual code which is sending these messages to the server, and the specific characters that are being sent?

Comment: 1. Here is the file that is responsible for forming ssh messages (Method name 'SendMessage(...)'): [Session.cs](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/Session.cs) 2. The exact string that is sent might be: "Hello" or "Hello\n" - the form of the message does not affect the behavior. 3. In the end everything goes down to the method [Socket.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w93yy28a(v=vs.110).aspx) in the .NET Framework.

Comment: "The exact string...might be: 'Hello' or 'Hello\n' - the form of the message does not affect the behavior" The `read` statement in the test_interactive script reads a line of input, so it'll block until it sees a line terminator or EOF. So yes, the form of the message ought to be able to affect the behavior.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for pointing me at this. I have tested this hypothesis before and I saw no difference between "..." and "...\n". Now I have cleaned my code and tested it again...and it works! I think I need to learn something from this situation... ;) Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the [Kenster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13317/kenster) I have found the answer.

#### Yes, sshd sends data into *stdin* after 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST exec'.

But you need to be careful with what you are sending. In my case, the methods that formed the response message erased ***'\n'*** character from the stream. This character was needed for shell function ***read*** to proceed.